# select top n posts by score count

Tags: group-by, hive

I am trying to get the top n users by post using hive.  The table looks like this.

```
Score    User
10       1
20       2
50       1
20       2
0        3
3        1
40       2
...
```

I want to generate output which shows like

```
Rows    Users
3       1
3       2
1       3
```

here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(score) as Score, UserID AS COUNT FROM A WHERE UserID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY UserID,score LIMIT 10) A;
```

The output I get is something like this

```
0   0
0   1
0   2
0   3
0   4
0   5
0   6
0   7
0   8
0   9
```

Can someone guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: you need to group by score instead of userid. row can be received using id

Comment: If I use group by on score like this `SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(score) as Score, UserID AS COUNT FROM A WHERE UserID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY score LIMIT 10) A;` then I get an error `Expression not in GROUP BY key UserId'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(score) as Score, UserID FROM A WHERE UserID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY UserID LIMIT 10
```